# Write a program using while loop, which prints the sum of every fifth number from 0 to 500 (including both 0 and 500)

Tags: python

This is what I have done:
Can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

```
num = 0
    x = 1
    while x <= 500:
        num += x
        x += 5

    print(num)
```

Comment: Why are you starting with `x=1` instead of `x = 0`?

Comment: start from `x=0` rather than `x=1`

Comment: Will do! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is your program or your question edit issue, but please check your code indentation...

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is also wrong. It needs to be like this

```
num = 0
x = 0
while x <= 500:
        num += x
        x += 5
        print(num)
```

But, if you want to print only the final sum, you can use the print statement outside loop

```
num = 0
x = 0
while x <= 500:
        num += x
        x += 5
print(num)
```

Comment: I want to print the sum of every fifth number!

Comment: That's fine. You can try my first code.

Answer (score 0):

Logic: We have to use while loop to check every number. We have to check whether the number is divisible by 5 or not, for that, we have to put if condition and keep on adding +1 to go from 0 to 500. If the condition is satisfied, add to to a variable whose initial value is 0. You code:

```
x=0
r=0
while x<=500:
    if x%5==0:
        r+=x
    x+=1
print(r)
```

Or you can do it this way, start the initial value from 0, updating value of x should be  5, add it to variable whose initial value is 0. You alternative code:

```
x=0
r=0
while x<=500:
    r+=x
    x+=5
print(r)
```

The second code will help you rectify your personal code. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
x = 0
acc = 0
while (x := x + 5) <= 500:
    acc += x
```

Here we use an assignment operator inside `while()` to get the value while incrementing it at the same time.